# c/c++ ptr arithmetic with number not divisible by 4

Tags: c++

I am needing to learn about ptr arithemtic for a class, but I am confused by something.

I understand that the ptr incrementation is basically multiples of 4, so if...

ptr++ basically = 4bytes
as does
ptr = 1

my question is what if you want to make the ptr equal something that isn't divisible by 4, like say 2606.

in the code that I need to modify we see...

ptr = ptr + 652;

this would equal 2608
if I change the code to...

ptr = ptr + 651

then it equals 2604

what do I need to do to modify this to make the ptr equal 2606?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "ptr incrementation is basically multiples of 4"... What? That is in no way correct, except in the very specific case of the pointed type being exactly 4 bytes in size...

Comment: _"I understand that the ptr incrementation is basically multiples of 4 ..."_ Not really at all.

Comment: "In case you're wondering about 1 == 4: Remember that earlier, I mentioned that ints are four bytes on current Intel processors. So, on a machine with such a processor, adding 1 to or subtracting 1 from an int pointer changes it by four bytes. Hence, 1 == 4. (Programmer humor.)"

http://boredzo.org/pointers/#arithmetic

Comment: *"ints are four bytes"* not guaranteed either, it is up to the compiler vendor to decide that.

Comment: This quote is specifically about **int** pointers. The rule is that a pointer is incremented by multiplies of it's size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, pointer arithmetic is not generally in multiples of 4. It is in multiples of the size of the pointed-to type -- and it's valid only when both the starting value and the resulting value point to elements of the same array object, or just past the end of it.

For example, given:

```
int arr[10];
int *ptr = &arr[0];
```

the expression `ptr + 3` yields `&arr[3]`.  That will be 3*4 bytes after the address of `ptr[0]` *if and only if* `sizeof (int) == 4`.  If `arr` is an array of `char`, and `ptr` is a `char*`, then `ptr + 3` is still `&arr[3]`, but it's only 3 bytes after `&arr[0]`.

Any operation that tries to add a fraction of the element size to a pointer is invalid. You can try to do it by casting the pointer to `char*`, performing the addition, and then casting back, but the result will be misaligned, and the behavior is undefined. Don't do that.

Comment: `size of the pointed-to type` means for different types this value can be changed (for ex: char vs double) or it may change between the platform (for ex: 32 vs 64) which has different addressing scheme and different pointer sizes (4 vs 8 bytes)?

Comment: @Deniz The size of the type is primarily dependent on the compiler. The standard makes very few guarantees in terms of type sizes (except for fixed width types such as `int32_t`).

Comment: @UnholySheep I am not talking about the size of type, talking about the size of the pointer. Size of a pointer does not depend on the type it points, right?

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes it is, nevermind, explanation in the answer is correct, I just confused by the phrase.

Comment: @Deniz: The size of a pointer type is also implementation-defined. On most modern implementations, all pointers happen to be the same size, but you shouldn't depend on that. The size of a pointer type is not generally related to the size of the type it points to.